# How to setvalue on fieldupdate

Tags: c#, asp.net, acumatica

Hello i am still having issue on my customization project i am using acumatica and i need to get the corresponding field on pxselect or on field update can you show me a way of doing this i have tried everything that i learned here.

so here is the code i created

```
 public class APTranExt : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.AP.APTran>
        {
            #region UsrWholdingATC
            [PXDBString(10)]
            [PXUIField(DisplayName = "WholdingATC")]
            [PXSelector(
            typeof(Search<withholdingtaxx.atc>),
                typeof(withholdingtaxx.taxRate))]
            public virtual string UsrWholdingATC { get; set; }
            public abstract class usrWholdingATC : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<usrWholdingATC> { }
            #endregion

            #region UsrWholdingrate
            [PXDBDecimal]
            [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Wholdingrate")]

            public virtual Decimal? UsrWholdingrate { get; set; }
            public abstract class usrWholdingrate : PX.Data.BQL.BqlDecimal.Field<usrWholdingrate> { }
            #endregion

            #region UsrWholdingamount
            [PXDBDecimal]
            [PXUIField(DisplayName = "WholdingAmount")]

            public virtual Decimal? UsrWholdingamount { get; set; }
            public abstract class usrWholdingamount : PX.Data.BQL.BqlDecimal.Field<usrWholdingamount> { }
            #endregion
            [Serializable]
        public class withholdingtaxx : IBqlTable
        {
            #region IDNbr
            [PXDBInt(IsKey = true)]
            [PXUIField(DisplayName = "IDNbr")]
            public virtual int? IDNbr { get; set; }
            public abstract class idNbr : PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<idNbr> { }
            #endregion

            #region Atc
            [PXDBString(50, IsUnicode = true, InputMask = "")]
            [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Atc")]
            public virtual string Atc { get; set; }
            public abstract class atc : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<atc> { }
            #endregion

            #region Type
            [PXDBString(50, IsUnicode = true, InputMask = "")]
            [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Type")]
            public virtual string Type { get; set; }
            public abstract class type : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<type> { }
            #endregion

            #region Description
            [PXDBString(400, IsUnicode = true, InputMask = "")]
            [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Description")]
            public virtual string Description { get; set; }
            public abstract class description : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<description> { }
            #endregion

            #region TaxRate
            [PXDBString(50, IsUnicode = true, InputMask = "")]
            [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Tax Rate")]
            public virtual string TaxRate { get; set; }
            public abstract class taxRate : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<taxRate> { }
            #endregion

            #region Bir_form
            [PXDBString(50, IsUnicode = true, InputMask = "")]
            [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Bir_form")]
            public virtual string Bir_form { get; set; }
            public abstract class bir_form : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<bir_form> { }
            #endregion
        }
        }
```

everything from here is working just fine i successfully created a custom table the show table from pxselector

[image]

so what i need is when i select atc value i need to also pull the tax rate and put it at wholdingrate field thank you for helping

by the way i tried to put some codes here but it does not hit the fieldupdate when i run at debug mode

```
protected void APTran_UsrWholdingATC_FieldUpdated(PXCache cache, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {

      var row = (APTran)e.Row;

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it does not hit the fieldupdate when i run at debug mode

Usually this happens because the field editor control doesn't have property `CommitChanges` set to `True`:

[image]

When `CommitChanges` is set to `True` on the editor control the `FieldUpdated` event will be called when the control lose focus after the user has changed the value:

```
protected void APTran_UsrWholdingATC_FieldUpdated(PXCache cache, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
  APTran tran = e.Row as APTran;

  if (tran != null)
  {
    APTranExt tranExt = tran.GetExtension<APTranExt>();

    if (tranExt != null)
    {
       decimal? value = [...];
       cache.SetValue<APTranExt.usrWholdingrate>(tran, value);
    }
  }
}
```